# mock store throws an error when test is running

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs

This is the my test file

```
      import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'

import Stock from '../Stock'

const initialState = {}

const mockStore = configureStore()
const store = mockStore(initialState)

test('tets for the onUpdate function', () => {
  const props = {
    setErrorPopUp: jest.fn(),
    formSubmitAttempt: jest.fn()
  }
  const wrapper = shallow(<Stock {...props} store={store} />)
  wrapper.instance().onUpdate({ quantity: 0 })
  expect(props.setErrorPopUp).toHaveBeenCalled()

  wrapper.instance().onUpdate({ quantity: 3 })
  expect(props.formSubmitAttempt).toHaveBeenCalled()
}))
```

this throw an error when running a i could not debug the error need a hand to solve this issue

The error is following

```
tets for the onUpdate function

TypeError: state.get is not a function

  3 |  * Direct selector to the order state domain
  4 |  */
> 5 | const selectStockDomain = state => state.get('chefStock')
  6 | const selectAppDomain = state => state.get('app')
  7 |
```

what is the wrong with this code and how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You are likely using `immutableJS` in your store to add, get and remove data.

You can either use `immutableJS` to initialize your store

```
const initialState = fromJS({ key: 'val' })
```

or

You could initialize your store with a dummy `get()` function

```
const initialState = { get: () => {}}
```

Comment: I have change that , now it giving me a error that the property of a selector is undifined

`` TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetching' of undefined

      12 |   createSelector(
      13 |     selectStockDomain,
    > 14 |     ({ fetching }) => fetching
      15 |   )
      16 |``